# How can I find out the width of an image that hasn't been styled in JavaScript (in IE)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, height, width

Imagine you have the following

```
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "MahImage.jpg";
    x.appendChild(img);
```

What can I do to find out the Width and Height of the image without using jQuery?

I am currently using .width , which works fine for any intelligent browser, but I have to find out a way to make IE happy

Comment: What version of IE isn't this working in? It works in 8 for me fine, and I'm sure I've had it working in older versions.

Comment: I am using IE7 and it doesn't seem to like it

Comment: I just discovered something... IE cannot find out the width of hidden images, I just made it visible b4 getting W and H and it works, thank you all, now I am just going to an hero

Answer (score 0):

After image load's you can access to properties `width` and `height`.

For example:

```
alert(img.height + img.width);
```

Also you can get image dimensions using properties `clientHeight` and `clienWidth`

To know if image loaded use `onload` hanler.

For example

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "MahImage.jpg";
img.onload = imageproperties;
x.appendChild(img);

function imageproperties() {
    alert(img.height + img.width);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, that works fine for any intelligent browser, and it's what I do now, but I need a solution that actually works for Internet Explorer (*editing question*)

Comment: Try `clientHeight` and `clientWidth`

Comment: returns 0, and I have to write random stuff cos otherwise the comment is too short

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `width` and `height` properties of the image, but they will only return a useful value once the image has loaded; so you'll only want to access them inside the `onload` event of the image (or give it a reasonable time to load).

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function () {
    this.height;
    this.width;
};
img.src = "MahImage.jpg";
x.appendChild(img);
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aS7a7/

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because you cant find the height/width of an image until after it is done loading.  This means you'll need a callback attached to the load of the image:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "MahImage.jpg";
img.onload = imageReady;
x.appendChild(img);

var imageReady = function() {
  alert(img.height); 
  alert(img.width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the image will be loaded. Here is the code (tested in Chrome):

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://google.ru/logos/2011/Albert_Szent_Gyorgyi-2011-hp.jpg";
img.onload = function(){
    console.log(img.width, img.height);
}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
```